# tidyverse replacement for reshape() for panel data with round suffix

Tags: r, reshape, tidyverse

What is the `tidyverse` replacement for `reshape()` in this example? I want the wide version to take the name of the round: `v2.1` and `v2.2`. I thought it should be `gather()`, but I haven't figured it out.

```
library(tidyverse)
r1 <- data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 3),
                 v1=c(1, 1, 0),
                 v2=c(0, 1, 1),
                 round=c(1, 1, 1))

r2 <- data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 3),
                 v2=c(1, 0, 0),
                 round=c(2, 2, 2))

r12 <- bind_rows(r1, r2)

r12w <- reshape(r12,
                timevar = "round",
                v.names = "v2",
                idvar = "id",
                direction = "wide")
r12w

#  id v1 v2.1 v2.2
#1  1  1    0    1
#2  2  1    1    0
#3  3  0    1    0
```

---

**Updated** example with unbalanced rows across datasets.

```
r1 <- data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 v1=c(1, 1, 0, 0),
                 v2=c(0, 1, 1, 1),
                 round=c(1, 1, 1, 1))

r2 <- data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 3),
                 v2=c(1, 0, 0),
                 round=c(2, 2, 2))
```

This mimics a panel survey where some people are not found/refuse in later rounds. Here, person 4 is in `r1`, but not `r2`. We want to keep this person in the final dataset, but with a NA value for `v2`. Here is the desired output. Looking for a tidverse approach to go from `r1` and `r2` to this output.

```
#  id v1 v2.1 v2.2
#1  1  1    0    1
#2  2  1    1    0
#3  3  0    1    0
#4  4  0    1   NA
```

Comment: Your example doesn't really work properly with `reshape` either as `v1` has values you are discarding (notice the warning message?). `reshape(r12, idvar="id", timevar="round", direction="wide")` and then fixing it up after the fact would probably be preferential.

Comment: I don't think `v1` gets dropped. It only appears in `r1` with values `c(1, 1, 0)`. Those values remain in the final `r12w`. Am I missing something?

Comment: `r21$v1` has 6 values. You only end up with 3 in the final set. R even warns you about this "*some constant variables (v1) are really varying*". The result is also dependent on the order of rows - e.g.: `reshape(r12[6:1,], timevar = "round", v.names = "v2", idvar = "id", direction = "wide")` gives all `NA`s for `v1`

Comment: that's true, but they are missing by design. this variable only exists in `r1` and the intermediate step of `bind_rows()` creates NAs. it is not really a varying variable in my panel, just as an artifact of `bind_rows()`.

Comment: As @thelatemail mentioned, the example is not clear with respect to the output.  If you are saying that NA elements in 'v1' should match the 'v2.2', then you may need to replace the `NA` elements with non-NA elements i.e.  `r12 %>% mutate(v1 = replace(v1, is.na(v1), v1[!is.na(v1)])) %>% mutate(round = paste0("v2.", round)) %>% spread(round, v2)`

Comment: @akrun your `spread()` approach gets the right output...same as i get with `reshape()`. can i do something other than `bind_rows()` in the previous step to go from `r1` and `r2` to your final output without having to do the first `mutate()` step for `v1`?

Comment: I think you may need to create the column before the `bind_rows` i.e. `nm1 <- setdiff(names(r1), names(r2));r2[nm1] <- r1[nm1]; bind_rows(r1, r2) %>% mutate(round = paste0("v2.", round)) %>% spread(round, v2)`
`

Comment: ah ha! that works. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understand what you want but here is an attempt:

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(r1, r2, by = "id", suffix = c(".1", ".2")) %>%
  select(-starts_with("round"))
```

Answer (score 1):

We create the missing column in 'r2' before doing the `bind_rows` by assigning that column from 'r1'.  For this, we can use `setdiff` to get the column that is found in 'r1' and not in 'r2'.  Then, `paste` the string 'v2.' with 'round' column and `spread` to 'wide' format

```
m1 <- setdiff(names(r1), names(r2))
r2[nm1] <- r1[nm1]
bind_rows(r1, r2) %>%
      mutate(round = paste0("v2.", round)) %>%
      spread(round, v2)
#  id v1 v2.1 v2.2
#1  1  1    0    1
#2  2  1    1    0
#3  3  0    1    0
```

NOTE: Here, we are assuming that the datasets have the same number of rows

Comment: thanks for adding this note. the approach definitely works with my toy example, but it would not work with my actual use case since my equivalents of `r1` and `r2` have different numbers of rows.

Comment: @EricGreen In that case, please update your example.  Then it is is not clear which value from 'r1' should go into 'r2'